# Porting Managed C# code to Unmanaged C++ code - Threads, Registry classes

Tags: c#, c++, .net, unmanaged, createthread

I am porting managed code to unmanaged code.
I have APIs in managed code from these below namespaces

```
using namespaces System::Threading::Tasks;
using namespaces System::Registry;
```

I have converted Registry APIs.
I am facing problem in converting

```
// Managed Code
Task::Factory->StartNew(gcnew Action(this, &MymanagedClass::ManagedFn));
```

Please let me know how to proceed with the porting.

Comment: I would suggest [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)

Comment: Hi CoryKramer, Thanks, But I am not supposed to use c++11 standards. So I have to see other options.